# How to split images with cv2?

Tags: python, opencv

I have image **paint.bmp**. And I want to split it into 32x32 blocks. Here's my code:

```py
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('paint.bmp')
img_h, img_w = image.shape[:2]
bl_w, bl_h = 32, 32

for i in range(int(img_h/bl_h)):
  for j in range(int(img_w/bl_w)):
    cropped = image[i*bl_h:bl_h, j*bl_w:bl_w]
    cv2.imwrite("Cropped image{}{}.bmp".format(str(i+1), str(j+1)), cropped)
```

The first block is saving, but after it programs crashes with:
`cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:715: error (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite'`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at line
`cropped = image[i*bl_h:bl_h, j*bl_w:bl_w]`

In the first block, you slice like this: `image[0:32, 0:32]`, which is works fine. But, in the second block you are trying to take `image[32:32, 32:32]`, which will always return en empty array.

There is a simplier way to do this:

```py
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('image.bmp')
img_h, img_w = image.shape[:2]
bl_w, bl_h = 32, 32

for i in range(int(img_h/bl_h)):
  for j in range(int(img_w/bl_w)):
    cropped = image[i*bl_h:(i+1)* bl_h, j*bl_w:(j+1)*bl_w]
    cv2.imwrite("Cropped image{}{}.bmp".format(str(i+1), str(j+1)), cropped)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://pypi.org/project/empatches/

works well and it allows you to set the stride if you want to overlap patches as well as recombining patches later

```
from empatches import EMPatches
from cv2 import imread

original_image= imread("blah.png")

emp = EMPatches()
patchsize = 32
stride = 32

# to split
patches, indices = emp.extract_patches(
        original_image, patchsize=patchsize, stride=stride
    )

# process patches. In my case I extract a mask using unet (ML)    
new_patches = map(some_fn, patches)

# to recombine
recombined = emp.merge_patches(new_patches , indices , 'overwrite')
```

haven't tested the code above but this approach always works for me